# Brackets open source IDE doesn't display color in the syntax

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm working on a PHP script but the syntax of php is of white color. In other IDE the color of the syntax declaration is violet and the variable is colored with blue but here is all white. Maybe I must install some extension for enable it? I've current installed the PHP smart hint extension without results, any ideas?

Comment: Have you selected PHP in the language-drop-down in the bottom right corner?

Comment: I fixed. I've installed a custom theme.

Comment: Did the custom theme cause the problem or was it the solution?

Comment: Nope the custom theme is the solution. The default theme of Bracket doesn't have the colors in some language.